# How do I create an array of data for 30 days from database table where some dates are not entered?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say you have a simple table with:

```
ID  IP                  CREATED_DATE
-------------------------------------------------------
1   111.111.111.111     2011-03-28 14:12:31
2   111.111.111.111     2011-03-29 03:38:12
3   222.222.222.222     2011-04-02 12:04:45
4   111.111.111.111     2011-04-02 22:13:23
5   333.333.333.333     2011-04-03 05:53:15
6   222.222.222.222     2011-04-05 02:13:51
7   111.111.111.111     2011-04-07 11:45:34
```

I need to query the last 30 days and get a count of unique ips and total rows per day even if there are no entries for that day. So days that are not entered would obviously just be 0 as the array value for both unique and total rows.

Comment: Lol, I'm ok with building queries... but my head is fried right now. It's stumping me on how to include non-existent days in the query as either NULL or 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an [integers](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/07/the-integers-table/) table, you can generate all the days in your desired *timespan* and join those with the *tallies* of IPs for each day appearing in your table:

```
   SELECT timespan."day",
          COALESCE(num_uniq_ips, 0) AS num_uniq_ips,
          COALESCE(num_records, 0) AS num_records
     FROM (SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL i DAY) AS "day"
             FROM integers
            WHERE i < 30) timespan
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(created_date) AS "day",
                  COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS num_uniq_ips,
                  COUNT(1) AS num_records
             FROM so6025149
         GROUP BY 1) tallies
          ON timespan."day" = tallies."day"
 ORDER BY timespan."day" ASC;
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how this works. I've never used an integers table.

Comment: @Tomas, it's just a table (or view) of sequential integers.  I keep one around in MySQL with the numbers from 0 through 999 so that I can generate arbitrary ranges.  (Other RDBMS have functions that accomplish the same thing.)  If I need the past thirty days, as I do above, I can use the table's records 0 - 29 to compute today minus zero days, today minus one day, today minus two days ... today minus 29 days.  This gives me the range to fill in gaps missing in other tables when I want to compute something over each of those days...

Comment: ahh, gotcha... sure now I find out about this method. I'm going to give it a go right now.

Comment: @pilcrow, worked perfectly! Of course I needed to remove the double quotes from around "day" but other than that, creating the integers table and replacing the table name it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @pilcrow, I'm horrible at working with dates in mysql, is there a way to make the day formatted like mm/dd ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table, populate it with the past 30 days and use that in your query. From PHP code:

```
// create table with past 30 days
$buffer = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXIST past_month (val DATETIME NOT NULL );";
$now = new DateTime(now);
for($i=30;$i>0;$i++)
{
    $buffer += "INSERT INTO past_month VALUES(" . $now . ");";  
    $now->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
mysql_query($buffer);

// the query    
$sql= "SELECT
           val,
           (SELECT COUNT(IP) 
            FROM table 
            WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CREATED_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d) = DATE_FORMAT(val,'%Y-%m-%d') As                UNIQUE_IPS   
       FROM 
           past_month";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE ( DateTime > (GetDate()-30) )
```

something along those lines

Comment: It doesn't seem that this would fill in the missing dates, though.

Comment: That will only get distinct count and won't include the non-existant dates. I'm almost positive this can't be done in MySQL, but I'd love to be proved wrong!

Comment: If someone can come up with a PHP/MySQL combo that's simple and compact I'd go with that as well as an all in one query.